# Sending array values to a mysql database table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP file named with Set of HTML codes. The values for the textboxes are assigned and they prints as I needed.

```
<?
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
for($i=0; $i<5;$i++){

echo "<input name='C[]' value='$Texting[$i]' style='background-color:#D0A9F5;'></input>";

}
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save The Table" name="G"></input>'
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

And I need to store the values of the textboxes in an array and its to another PHP file in order to send the values to the database. This is a part of other PHP file.

```
<?
if(!empty($_POST['G'])){

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST['C']);$i++){

echo var_dump($_POST['C']);

$Query="INSERT INTO Questions(Questions_ID,Question_Name)          VALUES($i+1,'$_POST[C][$i]')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$Query)){

die("<script>alert( \"Error: ". mysqli_error($con)."\");window.location.href='FormCreationTrial.php';</script>");
```

}
}

```
}

?>
```

This is the var_dump of the array. array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(5) "Male2" [2]=> string(7) "Female2" }
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHIS\FinalSubmissionOfTheFormPHP.php on line 19. When I'm trying to send the array one by one it gives me an error like ' Duplicate entry 'Array[0]' for key 'Question_Name_UNIQUE'.

And This prints the size of the received array perfectly. I need to send those data to a table called 'questions. Keys of the array should be the primary key of the table named column ID and values of the array should go to questionType column of the table. How can I do this? could someone please give me a hint.

Comment: Why are you closing the body and html tag and then adding another input?

Comment: corrected it .. I couldn't find a suitable way to do it and give a try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$C = $_POST["C"];
```

try this in your php file to get contents of the post input field and from here you could just open this array

```
foreach($C as $value)
{
     //your database code here if mysql 
     //$value is your value

}
```

i would prefer if you would do

```
var_dump($C);
```

this would show you all the contents getting stored inside your array and then you can store the value according to that

Comment: Hello.......... Thankz for replaying.... :) I edited the question back could you plz let me knw why such an error is coming.

Comment: you dont need to add echo infront of var_dump it just works normally returns you everything inside a variable or array which is why you got that array to string conversion error. Apart from that for the query check your database, i assume there are entries before that which is why its clashing the best way to do that would be to make that field auto increment so you dont even have to add anything to the field database would auto increment itself