# Submitting values from an array of textboxes into a mysql database table using a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to continue from answer given for the question [Sending array values to a mysql database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025438/sending-array-values-to-a-mysql-database-table)

Here we find that to enter the array of values foreach loop is used. Can we use a single query to insert all. Because if one query inside the loop fails to execute all will be in vain.

Comment: Post the details here,questions are not telenovellas.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    foreach($C as $value)
    {
    try
    {
         //your database code here if mysql 
         //$value is your value
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
{
throw new Exception;
}
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    continue;
    }

    }
```

**If somehow a query fails to execute**, it will move to the next iteration and will work successfully.